# Declare local jar file as a transitive dependency of a library project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android app (App1) that depends on a library project (Lib1). The library project has several remote dependencies (e.g. guava, android support library, etc) and two local dependencies, which are JAR files stored in the Lib1/libs/.

This is how the dependencies section of the build.gradle of Lib1 looks like:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:r08'
}
```

If I compile just the library (i.e. running `gradle assemble` on the Lib1/ folder) then it compiles correctly but when I add the library as a dependency of App1 then gradle complains that that it cannot find the two jars in the libs/ folder of Lib1.

This is the build.gradle of App1:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':Lib1')

  compile 'org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:0.7.2'
  compile 'org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-webdav:2.3.6'
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to tell gradle that if a library depends on local jar files then projects that depend on that library should also include them as dependencies? Remote dependencies work fine but not when you have jar files in libs/.