# Gradle transitive dependency to JAR inside of a library module

Tags: java, android, jar, gradle

I'm migrating an Android multi-module project from Ant to Gradle. 
We have some jars in the repo in the libs directory of a library module.

The dependency is as follows:

AppModule depends on LibModule.

The code in AppModule cannot access contents of the library jar that is in LibModule. 
Although it can access from-source classes of LibModule (proving that the dependency in general is established).

Gradle documentation says, that all dependencies are transitive by default, but this experience seems to invalidate such claim. Is this a bug or is there some legitimate reason?

I've managed to hack it by adding a workaround dependency in AppModule:

```
compile fileTree(dir: '../LibModule/libs', include: ['*.jar']) // HACK!
```

But there should be a more DRY way to do this, right?

Gradle version: 2.1.

Interestingly, Android Studio appears to respect the transitiveness of the jar and does not signal an error.

The error occurs when I'm building using

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Thy typical java error is signalled:

```
error: package net.jcip.annotations does not exist
import net.jcip.annotations.NotThreadSafe;
                           ^
```

I know I can also specify deps in a maven-ish style, but we would like to be able to work with jars-in-the-repo as well, for our purposes.

TIA, Karol

Comment: for debugging purposes, it may be useful to check the Gradle task that Android studio is using (as it's clearly doing something different than what you're doing from the terminal). In Android Studio, go to View->Tool Windows->Gradle Console and then build your project.

Comment: Please show all relevant code (dependency declarations of AppModule and LibModule, etc.).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360737/gradle-how-do-i-include-a-local-jar-from-a-dependent-java-project-in-an-android?rq=1 - "This is not directly possible as local jars are not declared as transitive dependencies in Gradle."

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368748/declare-local-jar-file-as-a-transitive-dependency-of-a-library-project